# How to get back MDC "inheritance" with modern logback?

Tags: logback, slf4j, mdc

After going back to an older project and getting around to update its dependencies I had to realize that logback does not anymore propagate MDCs to children since version `1.1.5`: https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/commit/aa7d584ecdb1638bfc4c7223f4a5ff92d5ee6273

This change makes most of the logs nigh useless.

While I can understand the arguments given in the linked issues, I can not understand why this change could not have been made in a more *backwards compatible* manner (as is generally usual in java..).

**Q**: What is the now *correct* way to achieve the same behaviour other than having to subclass everything from Runnables to Threads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see no straightforward way to change this back. Two alternatives that come to mind are:

**Way #1: Wrap all `Runnable`s**

Introduce an abstract class that will copy `MDC` from the original `Thread` to a new `Thread` and use it instead of `Runnable`

```java
public abstract class MdcAwareRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private Map<String, String> originalMdc;

    public MdcAwareRunnable()
    {
        this.originalMdc = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        MDC.setContextMap(originalMdc);
        runImpl();
    }

    protected abstract void runImpl();

    /**
     * In case some Runnable comes from external API and we can't change that code we can wrap it anyway.
     */
    public static MdcAwareRunnable wrap(Runnable runnable)
    {
        return new MdcAwareRunnable()
        {
            @Override
            protected void runImpl()
            {
                runnable.run();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If some `Runnable` comes from an external API that you can't change that code, use `wrap` helper method.

Drawback: need to analyze and change whole code.

**Way #2: Mess with slf4j internals**

Resurrect the original `LogbackMDCAdapter` implementation that uses `InheritableThreadLocal` from before that commit and put it somewhere in your code under some other name. Then somewhere around startup use reflection to override [MDC.mdcAdapter](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/slf4j-api/src/main/java/org/slf4j/MDC.java#L68) property with and instance of that custom implementation. This is obviously a dirty hack but it saves a lot of troubles comparing to #1.

Note: for performance reasons it makes to inherit your resurrected version from existing `LogbackMDCAdapter` and just override all the methods with old implementation. See [LoggingEvent.java](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/LoggingEvent.java#L305) and [`LogbackMDCAdapter.getPropertyMap`](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/util/LogbackMDCAdapter.java#L161) internal method for some details.

**Way #3: Mess with logback jar** (even stranger alternative)

This sounds to me as a quite bad plan but for completness here it is.

Again resurrect the original `LogbackMDCAdapter` but this time don't rename, compile it and override that .class file inside logback.jar.

Or resurrect the original `LogbackMDCAdapter` with renaming, remove .class file for `org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder` from logback.jar and add your own class that will return resurrected version of `LogbackMDCAdapter` either to logback.jar or to your code. `MDC` seems to be bound to that class by name to create an implementation of `MDCAdapter` to use.

Or you can achieve similar result by using custom `ClassLoader` that would map `org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder` to your class instead of the one inside logback.jar. Note: this is probably impossible to achieve inside a Web-container that will add its own custom ClassLoaders.

Comment: Well, as yours has been the only answer you will get the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

**Way 4: Misuse TurboFilter**

`ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger` passes the logging event to a filter before passing it along to the appenders.

**Way 5: Modify log Encoder / provider**
Although this would mean the logging event is not updated, but the log output will be.

Answer (score 0):

**Way #6: create a custom configurator** defined [here](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#auto_configuration) (step 1), Set BasicMDCAdaper from slf4j before LogbackServiceProvider sets its internal LogbackMDCAdapter:

```
 @Override
 public ExecutionStatus configure(LoggerContext loggerContext) {
     JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
     loggerContext.setMDCAdapter(MDC.getMDCAdapter());
     configurator.setContext(loggerContext);
     return ExecutionStatus.NEUTRAL;
 }
```